# Methods for downloading tweets: X Api - accounts level for tweets download

Tags: pyspark, twitter

Could someone tell me if I really need twitter api basic account to pull tweets and save it to csv file?
For now I get message error that tells that I don't have permission so I assume that I need account with basic level not free.

Error which I got is:
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

I have read this documentatnion but I'm already totally lost. It seems that I need to pay for basic account for pulling tweets.

Can someone confirme my thoughts that this is only way to use twitter api?

Or are there some better methods to download a lot of tweets for ML purpose?

Thank you for all advice.

I already try this code in jupyter:

```
import tweepy

# API keys
    consumer_key = " "
    consumer_secret = " "
    access_token = " "
    access_token_secret = " "

# Auth set
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Obj creation
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Topic set
    query = "python"  # topic set
    tweets = api.search_tweets(q=query, count=10)  # Download 10 tweets

# Showing tweets
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(f"{tweet.user.screen_name}: {tweet.text}")
```